# How to implement INSERT IGNORE using hibernate in java?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, persistence, sql-insert

I'm using hibernate (mySql) and inserting rows by creating an instance of the class that is an `Entity` and then using `persist`.
I guess it is similar to `'INSERT'` statement.

I want to use `insert ignore` but don't know how to do it.

Here is an example :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test")
public class Test

@Column
private int test1;

@Cloumn
private int test2;
```

--> Inserting :

```
Test t = new Test();
t.setTest1 = 5;
t.setTest2 = 10;
t.persist(); // persist is taken from `EntityManager`
```

any help would be very appriciated!

Thanks a lot.